# how to avoid 'operation not permitted' with sudo command from hudson

Tags: macos, bash, hudson, sudo

I am trying to run a bash script on a MacOSX Node (master is on windows) through hudson,
but get `'Operation not permitted'` when script invokes `sudo` command (`su` as well).

I added the following line to
/etc/sudoers:

`'user' ALL:(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

'user' is logged on the Mac Node, java agent started with the same user.

still getting this error...
any idea ?

Comment: what is the command that is generating the error? You can see it by using 'set -x' in your script (no quotes)

Comment: just wrote 'sudo echo something' in the 'execute shell' section of my hudson job.

Comment: the error is on the command sudo itself: /usr/bin/sudo: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your syntax is wrong? On my OSX 10.6 I have:

```
username   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Note the equals vs. colon. I have no problem running sudo tasks either with Hudson or from command-line.

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake when copying the line to /etc/sudoers. However even if syntax is correct, I just can't do sudo from hudson.

Comment: dilig0: Check what's happening in your syslog (and authlog). I use sudo from hudson daily.